# How to get JSON Object from JSONNode Array?

Tags: json, jackson, jsonnode

I have a JsonNode which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "ObjectIWantToRetrieve": {
      "key0": {
        "key1": {
          "key2": "val3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I wish to get the ObjectIWantToRetrieve out
The equivalent of JsonNode.get("ObjectIWantToRetrieve"). Can anyone help me?
Should I be converting the JSONNode to ArrayNode Please advice thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert it to ObjectNode first like this :

```java
ObjectNode value = ((ObjectNode) JsonNode.get(0)).get("ObjectIWantToRetrieve")
```